# Are there 2 times initialization when there is a constructor with default argument

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

My question is about how the member data with initializer get initialized where there is also a default argument in the constructor.

```
class InputPlay {

    public:
        InputPlay(std::string s = "test" ) : _s(s) {  };

    private:
        std::string _s = "default";
};
```

**Question**:

Is there are going to be 2 times initialization for the variable **_s** when the construct is called? aka the **_s** will be initialized by the string literal **default** and then replace by the default argument "test" in the constructor?

Comment: Off-topic: As you do provide the argument by value (so a new object is created anyway), you might avoid *copying* this object into `_s` in favour of *moving* it: `: _s(std::move(s))`.

Comment: @Aconcagua very nice off-topic comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `_s` will only be initialized once.  The in class initialization is syntactic sugar for synthesizing a member initializer.  If you provide your own member initializer then the compiler will use that instead of synthesizing one for you from the in class initialization.

Answer (score 6):

No. For [non-static data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members), when both default member initializer and member initializer list are provided, the default member initializer will be ignored. That means `_s` will be initialized by the argument `s` of the constructor directly.

> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor, the default member initializer is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

`= "default";` is a *default* member initializer. It's the initializer to use for `_s` if you don't provide one. But since you do provide one (`_s(s)`) the default initializer never comes into player and `_s` is simply initialized to `s`.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) :

> If a non-static data member has an default member initializer and also appears in a member initializer list, then member initializer list is executed and the default member initializer is ignored:

Note that by definition something can only ever be initialized once. If something looks like it's initialized twice, it's usually being initialized and then assigned another value.